# How to cite website

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite a website but having no luck.  I found a website that said the following approach should work:

```
@ONLINE{Ford:2011:Online,
author = {Ford, Rebecca},
title = {Earthquake: Twitter Users Learned of Tremors Seconds Before Feeling Them {@ONLINE}},
month = Aug.,
year = {2011},
url = {http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/earthquake-twitter-users-learned-tremors-226481}
}
```

but this only yields the following output:

5] R. Ford. Earthquake: Twitter users learned of tremors seconds before feeling them @ONLINE, 2011.

Comment: Hi ngramsky, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You'll find it's a friendly group here :) I removed the Mactex tag, as that is reserved for questions explicitly concerning the distribution.

Comment: If that is what this website said, disregard it!  Get rid of the '{@ONLINE}' in the title field, for instance; also fix your 'month' field, especially if you are using `biblatex`, where the month field should be: `month = aug,` (or, better: `month = 8`).

Comment: I did as you suggested and the @ONLINE no longer appears, but the URL has yet to appear as well.  How do I ensure the URL itself is listed in the bib?

Comment: Well, you need to use a bibliography style that will print the url.  If you provide a minimal example of a `.tex` file, including the bibliography and citation commands, someone will surely be able to help you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a numeric style of some sort. The following works, although you will no doubt need to fiddle with the exact styling of titles and so forth. (Incidentally, note the correct way of using the date field.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{ford,
author = {Ford, Rebecca},
title  = {Earthquake: Twitter Users Learned of Tremors
          Seconds Before Feeling Them},
date   = {2011-08},
url    = {http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/earthquake-twitter-users-learned-tremors-226481}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

You can cite an online resource \cite{ford}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Citation of online resource]

Comment: Could you please add a reference or explain what format is expected by *biber* in order to process the *date* and *year* fields available to *@online*? Are the schemes `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-MM` used for *date* and are these the only allowed formats?

Comment: @JJD With biblatex and biber, you have more flexibility using `year` instead of `date`.