# Is there a "Hello World" Example of Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to create and cite a reference in Latex. Examples in the internet is are really all over the place. This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55999/how-to-cite-website) provided a very good example but alas, `\printbibliography` does not work. There is a rabbit hole of reasons why it does not work which I really do not care for. Can someone provide a working example source code for `BibLaTeX`?

Comment: There are books available on this subject ...

Comment: the example should work, so perhaps you should instead provide an error and the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There were no errors. The text "You can cite an online resource \cite{ford}." printed out just fine. However, there were no references that were loaded.

Comment: The example works if you run `pdflatex <filename>.tex`, then `biber <filename>`, then `pdflatex <filename>.tex` again. You only ran the first command.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141957/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864, though my favourite hello world example is https://gist.github.com/moewew/e92edad4f3b96d3ed9ef0308d61a6945. Keep in mind that a document using `biblatex` needs to be compiled with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...), see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you are having trouble getting the bibliography to show you may want to check the `.blg` file. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/.

Comment: @Sergio Thanks, it works. That is extremely unintuitive. Given how widespread Latex is, you'd think this should be solved with a click of a button in TexWorks.

Comment: All modern editors can be configured to do all that (and more) automatically in the background. It does help to know what's involved, though.

Comment: You might consider configuring TeXworks to use a wrapper like latexmk. Details [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18936/411).

Comment: You can configure texworks to run `biber` in same way that you run `pdflatex` and the other compilers. Then you only need to remember that is only an intermediate step (or use `latexmk`, but if you abuse of the previews, instead of make  a complete (and long) compilation every time,  it could better just run pdflatex only and pdflatex+biber only when you need to check new cites and references or so).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a fully working LaTeX installation, you need (1) a bibliography file in `biblatex` format, and (2) a document that calls the `biblatex` package and brings in your bibliography file with the `\addbibresource` command.

The easiest way to compile is to use `latexmk`, which will call the LaTeX engine and `biber` behind the scenes. You can customize the engine and other factors based on the arguments you give to `latexmk` (`latexmk -pdf` uses `pdflatex`, `-pdfxe` uses XeLaTeX, `-outdir=aux` sends all the output to the `aux` dir so you don't have to deal with all the log files, etc.).

You can customize the bibliography style by passing options to `biblatex` or calling another package built on it. For example, I use `biblatex-chicago` for citations according to the Chicago Manual of Style (`\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}`).

The bibliography file either needs to be in the same directory as the document file, or in your TeX path, such as in your local `$TEXMF` directory (`$HOME/texmf/tex/latex/local/` on my Linux system).

## Bibliography: `mybib.bib`

```
@Book{Knuth:TAOCP1,
    author={Knuth, Donald E.},
    title={The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms},
    shorttitle={The Art of Computer Programming I},
    location={Upper Saddle River, NJ},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley},
    year=1997,
    keywords={computer science, programming, mathematics, algorithms}
}
```

## Document: `mydoc.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{document}
See \autocite[1]{Knuth:TAOCP1}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## To compile PDF `doc.pdf`

```
latexmk -pdf doc.tex
```